# 401 Unauthorized making REST Call to Azure API App using Bearer token

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, adal

I created 2 applications in my Azure directory, 1 for my API Server and one for my API client. I am using the Python ADAL Library and can successfully obtain a token using the following code:

```
tenant_id = "abc123-abc123-abc123"
context = adal.AuthenticationContext('https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant_id)
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(
        'https://myapiserver.azurewebsites.net/',
        'myuser',
        'mypassword',
        'my_apiclient_client_id'
        )
```

I then try to send a request to my API app using the following method but keep getting 'unauthorized':

```
at = token['accessToken']
id_token = "Bearer {0}".format(at)
response = requests.get('https://myapiserver.azurewebsites.net/', headers={"Authorization": id_token})
```

I am able to successfully login using myuser/mypass from the loginurl. I have also given the client app access to the server app in Azure AD.

Comment: What's the full error you're getting?

Comment: Hi @yonisha, "response", in:

    response = requests.get('https://myapiserver.azurewebsites.net/', headers={"Authorization": id_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"})

evaluates to "<Response [401]>"

"response.content" is "You do not have permission to view this directory or page"

"response.reason" is "Unauthorized"

"response.status_code" is "401"

Comment: It seems like the access token is valid (invalid access token error message is different), but you're trying to access the wrong page.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that my app registration is misconfigured but cannot figure out exactly where / how.

Comment: Hi @Progger, have you had any luck resolving the issue, I am currently having the exact same issue and stumbled across this question here.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question was posted a long time ago, I'll try to provide an answer. I stumbled across the question because we had the exact same problem here. We could successfully obtain a token with the adal library but then we were not able to access the resource I obtained the token for.

To make things worse, we sat up a simple console app in .Net, used the exact same parameters, and it was working. We could also copy the token obtained through the .Net app and use it in our Python request and it worked (this one is kind of obvious, but made us confident that the problem was not related to how I assemble the request).

The source of the *problem* was in the end in the `oauth2_client` of the adal python package. When I compared the actual HTTP requests sent by the .Net and the python app, a subtle difference was that the python app sent a POST request explicitly asking for `api-version=1.0`.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common//oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
```

Once I changed the following line in `oauth2_client.py` in the adal library, I could access my resource.

Changed

```
return urlparse('{}?{}'.format(self._token_endpoint, urlencode(parameters)))
```

in the method `_create_token_url`, to

```
return urlparse(self._token_endpoint)
```

We are working on a pull request to patch the library in github.

Comment: FYI: the workaround described by @starsheriff is implemented in ADAL 0.4.3+. When you create `AuthenticationContext`, make sure pass in `api_version=None`. See more detail in [this conversation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/issues/54#issuecomment-261680626).

Answer (score 0):

For the current release of Azure Python SDK, it support authentication with a service principal. It does not support authentication using an ADAL library yet. Maybe it will in future releases.

See https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagement.html#authentication for details.

See also [Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/) for the platforms ADAL is available on.

Comment: Hi Derek - thanks for your response. I am not using the Python SDK at all. I am simply using Python to make a REST call to an endpoint using the Bearer token included in an Authorization header. I am also making the same REST call using Postman and having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry for that. I obtained a token using Service Principal and then made GET request, it worked. Due to limitations on my side, I can't use user credentials. Just a  reminder that when getting a token for a given resource via user credentials, you need to check whether the user is in your default AAD, if not, [createa a user in your default AAD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users/).

Answer (score 0):

@Derek,
Could you set your Issue URL on Azure Portal? If I set the wrong  Issue URL, I could get the same error with you. It seems that your code is right.
[image]

Base on my experience, you need add your application into Azure AD and get a client ID.(I am sure you have done this.) And then you can get the tenant ID and input into Issue URL textbox on Azure portal.

NOTE:

*On old portal(manage.windowsazure.com),in the bottom command bar, click View Endpoints, and then copy the Federation Metadata Document URL and download that document or navigate to it in a browser.
Within the root EntityDescriptor element, there should be an entityID attribute of the form https://sts.windows.net/ followed by a GUID specific to your tenant (called a "tenant ID"). Copy this value - it will serve as your Issuer URL. You will configure your application to use this later.*

My demo is as following:

```
import adal
import requests

TenantURL='https://login.microsoftonline.com/*******'
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(TenantURL)
RESOURCE = 'http://wi****.azurewebsites.net'
ClientID='****'
ClientSect='7****'
token_response = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    RESOURCE,
    ClientID,
    ClientSect
)
access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')
print(access_token)
id_token = "Bearer {0}".format(access_token)
response = requests.get(RESOURCE, headers={"Authorization": id_token})
print(response)
```

Please try to modified it. Any updates, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks for your response. I already had everything setup exactly the way you suggested with one difference: I am not using client_id and client_secret. I am using "acquire_token_with_username_password" instead of "acquire_token_with_client_credentials" I will need clients to authenticate using username and password. Can you try this and see if it works for you?

Comment: @Progger, Could you try to use the Fiddler to send REST API with the access_token?

Comment: I already used Postman but what I will try next is using client credentials instead of username / password and see if that works.